# Automapper: update collection

Tags: c#, automapper

Code:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "")] public void Test1() 
{ 
    var definition = new Definition 
    { 
        Hash = "hash1", 
        Link = "link1", 
        Name = "name1" 
    };

    var view = new View
    {
        Hash = "hash2",
        Id = Guid.Parse("ab8a6aac-532d-43af-aa0a-3781f0da3d96"),
        Link = null,
        Name = "name2"
    };

    var views = new List<View>
    {
        view
    };

    var definitions = new List<Definition>
    {
        definition
    };

     var collectionsMapping =_mapper.Map(definitions, views);
     var simpleMapping =_mapper.Map(definition, view);
}
```

Profile settings:

```
CreateMap<ReadFileDefinition, StandardFileView>();
```

Destination class:

```
public class View
{
    public Guid? Id{get;set;}
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public string? Hash { get; set; }
    public string? Link { get; set; }
}
```

Source class:

```
public class Definition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, class 'Definition' is missing property 'Id'. When you try to update property 'Id' for the collection 'List<View>'(see 'collectionsMapping'), it is always null.
But for 'simpleMapping' it works fine and 'Id' keep value from destination object.

[image] (collectionsMapping result)

[image] (simpleMapping result)

Question: How do i update property 'Id' for each collection member so that it stays from destination collection views?

Thx.

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping a single item will use the given destination instance and will not touch any unmapped properties (here the `Id` property).

Mapping a collection will create a **new** destination item for each source item and there you have the given default value from the class definition for any unmapped property.

You may want to customize the mapping to set the `Id` property in this case.

Comment: Do you mean to use the converter or resolver? Because you can't set it up via MapFrom..